# Newly added layers to QGIS 2.18 will not display in the print composer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, print-composer, ubuntu

I have an existing QGIS project that until today was just fine.  I added a new shapefile to the project but these new data fail to display in the print composer.  All other existing data in the project display just fine as do the other map elements in the print composer.  I have made no other alterations to the project or the print composer layout other than adding these data.

I have created a new blank project, added these data in question to the new project, created a new print composer, and confirmed that the data draw in this new project.  This leads me to believe this particular dataset in not the issue.

I have duplicated the print composer layout and this new layout has the same issue.

I have added other data for this area to the project and cannot view these data as well leading me to believe that there is some corruption in the print composer.

Please note that all data share the same CRS, and there were no alteration to any settings or elements in either the main display or the print composer.  This is happening on QGIS 2.18 with Ubuntu 16.04

What steps can I take to try to get my data to display in the print composer?

Comment: Have you clicked in item properties --> main properties the  update preview button? Does it change anything?

Comment: @geoSam, do you mean the Refresh button in the print composer?  Yes, I have and that refreshes the view but the data is question do not show.